# Excel - Matching Domains from Different Sheets

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have two excel sheets with email info on them. One list has full emails, the other list has email domains.

How can I see if any of the full emails, match the email domains in the other list?

In other words:
One list has X emails, the other list has Y email domains. How can I see which X email domains, are in the Y list.

Ideally, I'd have a True/False next to each indv. X email

Attached are the images for Y email domains, and X emails.

[Y Email Domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJpBw.png),
[X Emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cph8T.png)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following formula to extract the domain from the full email address:

```
=RIGHT(E1,LEN(E1)-FIND("@",E1,1))
```

Then use COUNTIF function to check if the domain appears on the domains list.

The formula will be something like:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10,RIGHT(E1,LEN(E1)-FIND("@",E1,1)))>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Considering the list of domains on range A2:A10 and the full email on range E1.